# Customer merging in netsuite via duplicate management tool gives error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, merge, netsuite, suitescript

The merge of the entity 'xxx' was blocked for the following reasons: The entities cannot be merged. Creation of the merged entity leads to following errors: You have modified the originating subrecord, and the clone can no longer be merged. To perform a merge, the clone's originating subrecord must not change before the merge. You must create a new clone. You have modified the originating subrecord, and the clone can no longer be merged. To perform a merge, the clone's originating subrecord must not change before the merge. You must create a new clone.

check subsidiary,currency,item price level etc

Comment: show the script, please